# Java: incompatible type at method argument

Tags: java, math, methods

I am trying to return this method:

```
private int x;
private int y;
private double pointOne;
private double pointTwo;


public Point (int newX , int newY)
{
    this.x = newX;
    this.y = newY;
}


public Point halfwayTo (Point other)
{
    pointOne = ((this.x + other.x)/2);

    pointTwo = ((this.y + other.y)/2);

    return new Point ("(" + pointOne + "," + pointTwo + ")");
}
```

A new point that is halfway of the given two points (midpoint formula).

However, I am getting an error "incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Point."

I need to return the two new point as (X, Y).

Answer (score 3):

The only constructor of [Point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html#Point-java.awt.Point-) with one parameter expect a Point object.

You are passing a string : `"(" + pointOne + "," + pointTwo + ")"`

hence the exception with message "String cannot be converted to Point".

Note that there is a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html#Point-int-int-) which expect two ints, you probably want to use this one instead.

---

As per your edit, you are using a custom `Point` object.

Check your imports, you are probably using [`java.awt.Point`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) while you think you use your custom `Point` object.

Comment: Nvm, I was looking at my Parameterized constructor. I have another copy constructor that only has one parameter. Ok I got what you are trying to say now. Thank you for the help.